# What's about import/export claims settings from WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: import, wso2, export, claims, wso2-identity-server

I can't find any information about import/export claims settings from WSO2 IS. Or may be another way to make DEV -> Test -> Preprod of WSO2 IS.

I developing application and add some claims, but I don't won't to add them to product server again, I would like to do it more correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating them at management console UI, you can update them directly at `repository/conf/claim-config.xml` and then migrate that file between the environments.

However this file will be read only on the tenant creation (first startup for the super tenant). After that point you can only modify them at the UI. So you need to make sure that you use a clean DB for IS in your new environment.